# licensing and/or Implementations?

Tags: licensing

How can I find out if this patent ([WO 2011160165 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/WO2011160165A1)) has been implemented in any hardware devices and whether it's available for licensing? Thank you.

Comment: Hi, Ask Patents is a website to ask about the patent process or to help find Prior Art on US Patent Applications and US Patents. Unfortunately, questions about the production of products covered by these patents is outside the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be aware that a Patent Cooperation Treaty (PCT) application published by the World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO) is not an issued patent.  It is really only a vehicle for preserving the right to pursue patent protection in PCT "contracting states" by later entering the national/regional phase (i.e., filing a national stage patent application) of the jurisdiction in question.

Second, you should be aware that patents are geographical in nature.  A US patent, for example, only provides its owner with exclusionary rights within the US.

In this case, the published PCT application you cite appears only to have entered into the national phase in Australia (see: http://www.lens.org/lens/patent/WO_2011_160165_A1/family).  So, unless you plan on using the claimed invention in Australia, you may not need a license.

You may want to look at products of Fetch TV Pty Limited (the assignee) to determine if they have implemented devices incorporating the claimed invention.  The assignee would also be a place to start for determining the availability of a license.